# Adding filters to AWS cost SDK in GO

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk

I am using aws go sdk and accessing the cost data from AWS. This query returns all ths services in an aws account like S3, EC2...

```
result, err := svc.GetCostAndUsage(&costexplorer.GetCostAndUsageInput{
            TimePeriod: &costexplorer.DateInterval{
                Start: aws.String(startDate),
                End:   aws.String(endDate),
            },
            Granularity: aws.String(granularity),
            GroupBy: []*costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
                &costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
                    Type: aws.String("DIMENSION"),
                    Key:  aws.String("SERVICE"),
                },
            },
            Metrics: aws.StringSlice(metrics),
        })
```

How can I add a filter to this query so I can retrieve data of a few selected services ?

Answer (score 0):

The docs ([link](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/costexplorer#GetCostAndUsageInput)) show there's a field in the `costexplorer.GetCostAndUsageInput` struct called `Filter` that's a [`*types.Expression`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/costexplorer@v1.21.2/types#Expression), which has a field named `CostCategories` that's a [`*types.CostCategoryValues`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/costexplorer@v1.21.2/types#CostCategoryValues) that should do the trick.

Here's your code but modified to filter only costs for S3 (fair warning, this code has not been tested):

```
result, err := svc.GetCostAndUsage(&costexplorer.GetCostAndUsageInput{
            Filter: &types.Expression{
                CostCategories: &types.CostCategoryValues{
                    Key: aws.String("SERVICE"),
                    Values: []string{"s3"}, // 's3' may not be the right value here, this is just an example
                },
            },
            TimePeriod: &costexplorer.DateInterval{
                Start: aws.String(startDate),
                End:   aws.String(endDate),
            },
            Granularity: aws.String(granularity),
            GroupBy: []*costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
                &costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
                    Type: aws.String("DIMENSION"),
                    Key:  aws.String("SERVICE"),
                },
            },
            Metrics: aws.StringSlice(metrics),
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But this didn't work for me. Instead I was able to get it in the following way :- 

Filter: &costexplorer.Expression{
    Dimensions: &costexplorer.DimensionValues{
     Key: aws.String("SERVICE"),
     Values: aws.StringSlice(requiredService),
    },